# How to check exist files are not corrupted in android?

Tags: android, file, corrupt

I have list of files ,in that files some files are **corrupted** or **null**.

how to **corrupted** or **null** differentiate files?

suppose, I have 10 **JPEG** files in that 8 files working and 2 are corrupted size of with **120 KB** and **0 KB**,  similarly for other files like text,media and so on...
In this case **0 KB** files are differentiate but how i can differentiate files have some size like **120 KB , 150 KB,1 MB and so on...** ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are downloading and saving a file you can cross check MD5 hash with server to check whether file got corrupted or If you have working file then save its MD5 hash for later comparison.